# Cannot assign int to a variable in Go

Tags: go, int

Go version - 1.2.1

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    type INTEGER int
    var aa INTEGER
    var bb INTEGER
    aa, bb = F(100,50)
    fmt.Println(aa,bb)
}

func F(a int, b int) (sum int, difference int){
    return a+b, a-b
}
```

### Output:

/g.go:9: cannot assign int to aa (type INTEGER) in multiple assignment
./g.go:9: cannot assign int to bb (type INTEGER) in multiple assignment

Comment: Go version 1.2.1 is an obsolete, unsupported version. The [current version](https://golang.org/dl/) is Go 1.5.1.

Comment: @peterSO So is the behaviour different in Go 1.5?

Comment: Whether it is different or not (it isn't) doesn't matter, and answers should target Go 1.2.1.

Comment: My point is: this is IMO a very valid question and it doesn not deservere 5 down votes.

Answer (score 7):

`type` creates a new type, so this will obviously fail. You have to explicitly convert the values from `int` to `INTEGER`:

```
aaInt, bbInt := F(100, 50)
aa, bb = INTEGER(aaInt), INTEGER(bbInt)
```